# Vue component with slot contents converted to google maps marker

Tags: vue.js

I know there is a [google maps vue](https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps) library, but I am working in a codebase that has already created some of its own similar components.

In particular, I have a component that wraps [rich-marker](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-rich-marker/reference.html) in vue, exposing a slot which is rendered as a rich marker on the map.

To make this work I need to provide a `div` to the google api, and I'd like the content of this `div` to reflect the contents of the `slot`.  Using a render function seems to partly work as follows (roughly):

```
render(createElement){
   let content = createElement('div', this.$slots.default);
   this._marker = new RichMarker({
      content: content,
      map: this.map
   });
   return content;
}
```

But it sometimes causes problems because the DOM nodes under control of Vue are being moved around the tree (google maps is putting them wherever it needs to).  This is shown by the following error:

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': 
The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.
```

To avoid this I can think of several options:

1. Convert the `$slots.default` `VNode` into an actual DOM node somehow, and supply that to google (and have the render function return a dummy empty `div`).
2. Let Vue render the slot where it wants to, but use css to hide it, and then copy the `innerHTML` to a new `div` for google.
3. Do some kind of wrapping hack, where I move an inner element but leave the outermost element so that Vue doesn't get confused.

I wasn't able to find anything that would let me do option (1.). Does anyone know if there is an undocumented part of Vue that would let me do this?

I did try option (2.) but the `update` lifecycle event didn't seem to do what I needed as it didn't fire when the slot contents changed. I'm also not sure if it is guaranteed to fire after the true DOM has rendered.

I also tried option (3.) but had similar problems to options (2.). In fact, I'm not sure that option (3.) is really going to work because Vue needs to mutate the slot-related nodes as well as the marker component's node.

**UPDATE:**
I have managed to make option (3.) work in the end. The render function now looks roughly like this:

```
render(createElement){
   this._otherEl = this._otherEl || document.createElement('div');
   let elInner = createElement('div', this.$slots.default);
   let el = createElement('div', {}, [elInner]);
   if(this.$el && this.$el.firstChild && this._otherEl.firstChild !== this.$el.firstChild){
     this._otherEl.firstChild && this._otherEl.removeChild(this._otherEl.firstChild);
     this._otherEl.appendChild(this.$el.firstChild);
   }

   this.marker = new RichMarker({
      content: this._otherEl,
      map: this.map
   });
   return el;
}
```

And `marker` needs to be declared in the `data` of the component (for some reason that I didn't investigate further).